# When getting coconut milk out of a coconut what type of drill bit should I use?

Tags: coconut, lime

I'm aware there's wood, masonry, and metal drill bits, but what type works best for getting milk out of a coconut to put lime in it?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tbgv8PkO9eo

Comment: The one time I did this, I didn't use a drill and that sounds wrong to me.

Comment: Coconuts are not filled with milk. They're filled with coconut **water**. The product we know as "coconut milk" comes from grinding the flesh. Are you trying to get coconut milk, or coconut water from your fresh coconut? The tools and process will be entirely different..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use a screwdriver and a small hammer to punch the eyes of the coconut in and then pour through a sieve into a receptacle.

It's important to have more than one opening to facilitate the juice coming out, otherwise an air-lock will quickly form.

Wearing a gorilla suit is recommended, but entirely optional.

Comment: Where do I get a gorilla suit?

Comment: So I should just use the scratch awl?

Answer (score 2):

Coconuts are pretty soft as drillable things go. Wood or metal bits would be fine. A masonry bit might not work properly, as it's designed to be used with a different kind of drill.

Comment: Just make sure the bit is clean.

Comment: @GdD My first impulse at an answer: “a clean one”